# what is the best way to transfer back and forth between 2 activities

Tags: android

My application has a main form activity-1 with some `<EditTexts>` and a spinner, based on spinner selection, need to display another activity-2 with more form fields (multiselectable `<CheckBoxes>`), after user submitting the 2nd activity, need to display the activity-1 to allow the user to fill remaining fields of activity-1 (if any).
Finally, need to submit all the values from activity-1,2 to a webservice.

Can anybody please let me know the best way to do this.

Thanks,
nehatha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Activity-1 launch Activity-2 using startActivityForResult(intent). You can pass whatever info you want from Activity-1 to Activity-2 via intent extras using intent.putExtra() APIs. Then when Activity-2 is done, your Activity-1's onActivityResult() will be called.

Comment: Thank you Abhilash, do I need to send back the data received from Activity-1 + Activity-2's data to Activity-1 using putExtra() after Activity-2 is done?

Comment: Yes, once you are done with Activity-2 do this: setResult(RESULT_OK,bundle); finish();